# Azure Cloud Service error when deploying against v4.6.1

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am having a new issue when deploying Azure Cloud Services via Visual Studio 2015 SP1.

This is driving me up the wall and I am curious if  anybody else has seen this? Basically, I can build just fine, I just can't package for or publish to a Cloud Service - the error is:

**CloudServices232: The role MyProject.AsyncWorker is using an unsupported TargetFrameworkVersion v4.6.1.**

This wasn't happen a few weeks ago, but now I can't publish it. Yes I am targeting .NET 4.6.1 - but that has been WORKING JUST FINE for a while now and I followed all the steps to run install.cmd and manually deploy it.

This appears to be a new build-time error (it used to be a warning).

Comment: Started seeing this as well.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Which Guest OS version are you using - check `osVersion` in the .cscfg file? Also, does it work if published from azure portal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Supporting .net version 4.6 or higher in azure cloud service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199608/supporting-net-version-4-6-or-higher-in-azure-cloud-service)